# Mobile network 3g/4g randomly disconnects from the server

Tags: android, sockets, networking, server, client

I have a simple async client application for android that connects to a server on my desktop. Now over wifi the application works fine(unless the client network is super slow). But when I try to use it over the mobile network it randomly disconnects with the classic "connection reset by peer" error. I think the highest chance of it happening is connecting and then leaving it for a few seconds to do nothing over the connection. But the thing is sometimes it "survives" and happens later on, and maybe one in a hundred times doesn't disconnect at all. It makes no sense and there are a lot of applications on the appstore that work fine across mobile network so it can't be that hard...

EDIT: This also happens if i just put my phone on a table, great signal, no movement, or anything that would distrubt the connection.

Comment: Mobile networks are not as stable as a wifi connection.  People walk into buildings with too much steel in their frame, into parking lots, or have issues with the handoff between cell towers.  I don't know what you're doing with your service, but you probably need to make it more fault tolerant so you can survive disconnects

Comment: @GabeSechan True, I forgot to mention that it happens if i just put it on my table with no distrubtions etc. Added in EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of mobile's movement. You should check your setting in mobile network and keep only one setting 3g or 4g. Don't put this on "Both" connections.
Hope this will help.